# Serializable error Spring+Weblogic Cluster

Tags: spring, cluster-computing, weblogic11g

I have an application with Weblogic 11g in cluster, Spring 3 and JSF Mojarra.
There are: JavaBean (Serializable), ManagedBeans (Serializable for view/session), Service, DAO.

I got the error:

```
**All session objects should be serializable to replicate. 
Check the objects in your  session. Failed to replicate non-serializable object. 
java.rmi.MarshalException: failed to marshal update(Lweblogic.cluster.replication.ROID;ILjava.io.Serializable;Ljava.lang.Object;); nested exception is:
    java.io.NotSerializableException: com.emp.service.impl.DemandaServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4fae7872
```

Is it necessary to become serializable Service layer ? I do not want to put in session and replicate it.

Spring is running with:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Every Spring Bean in my applicationContext.xml automatically will be in HttpServletRequest, ServletContext or HttpSession?

If Yes, what is the solution to avoid Service layer serialization ?

Comment: I got it ! It was necessary to put transient in ManagedBeans to avoid serialization of other layers.

The trick was the following annotation in ManagedBean:
@Configurable(preConstruction=true, dependencyCheck=true)

When MangedBean is deserialized autowired atributes are injected again.